# Can java calss access NetNamedPipe and NetMsmq binding using WCF service

Tags: java, c#, wcf, binding

Is possible to access NetNamedPipe and NetMsmq binding service(WCF) through java class? or its reached by .net aplication only ?

Comment: `NetNamedPipe` and `NetMsmq` are specific to WCF and Microsoft.  However, you might be able to create something similar in Java (either natively or through a library).   I'm not 100% sure though.  You could look at the source code for those two classes and maybe get an idea.   It might require relying on lower-level Windows APIs.

Comment: @Tim:Thank you team for your input, so it means using java class we can not access wcf NetNamedPipe and NetMsmq binding service,Correct?

Comment: Unless there's a similar binding available in Java or you can build one, probably not.   For most interoperability scenarios you'll need to use one of the http bindings (basicHttpBinding in WCF is SOAP 1.1, and wsHttpBinding is SOAP 1.2).

Comment: @Tim:Noted,And thanks you for update